# Spring boot, empty multipart files

Tags: java, spring, http

A request comes from the service, multipart/form-data
http://joxi.ru/D2P5g6Eiq0NjjA

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*", params = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<?> createPost(
        @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allParameters,
        @RequestParam(value="data", required=false) CommonsMultipartFile locationMapFileData,
        MultipartHttpServletRequest mrequest,
        HttpServletRequestWrapper request,
        @RequestBody MultipartFile[] submissions
) {
   return sapService.createPost(allParameters);
}
```

Debug: http://joxi.ru/52a7XJySEMwG5r

what am I doing wrong? how can i get the contents of files?

p.s. sorry by translate english

Answer (score 1):

At first, the files are not the request body, they are part of it and there is no built-in HttpMessageConverter that can convert the request to an array of `MultipartFile`.

Thus, you need to specify the name of the part (there may be several parts with the same name), for example, we expect a few files under the "files" part:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<?> createPost(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] uploadFiles)   
{
  ...iterate over the uploadFiles and perform the necessary processing for each file
  return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```